# How to put border in a dynamic img tag?

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to put a border on my `img` tag. Here is my HTML.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row col-md-6">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{{design.img_url_front}}" border="5">
  </div>
  <div class="row col-md-6">
    <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="{{design.img_url_back}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

I also tried in CSS

```
img {
  border: 5px;
}
```

Still no luck.[image]

As you can see, I need the border around the blue part. How can I make it work? Please help.

Comment: img{
    border: 5px solid red;
}

Comment: Add border to `.img-responsive .center-block`

Comment: Did you try as : border: 5px solid;

Comment: thank you for answering and for the downvote. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `border` to the class `.img-responsive .center-block`

```
.img-responsive .center-block{
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to provide color,

try

```
img{
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```